# Custom Field is not visible at the time of "Edit mapping" in Data Import Wizard

Tags: data-import-wizard

I use data Import wizard to import lead i have two custom field StateCode And Countrycode. when mapping field in the "Edit mapping" section of the Data import wizard. Statecode and countrycode is visible to me but when my client want to import same csv he will not able to see those custom fields. Both of us are System Adim profile. Can you please help to get out of this.

And when i was login with client user name and password. And then use data import wizard, now I am able to to see both stateCode and countryCode. can any one explain how this was happen it is totally strange for me.

Comment: Have you tried doing a data export to CSV so he can see the fields?

Comment: Please refer updated question i will find another strange thing.